# Get Result from 1 MySQL table with 3 Joins and add new rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got this kind of table:

```
<-T1->

name    rnk     rce     pts     elo

p1      1       1       15      1021
p2      2       1       12      1010
p3      3       1       8       960
p1      2       2       12      1030
p2      1       2       15      1020
p3      3       2       8       975
p1      1       3       15      1030
p2      2       3       12      1025
p3      3       3       8       970
p1      2       4       12      1038
p2      1       4       15      1028
p3      3       4       8       956
```

and the result should look like this:

```
<-result->

name    wins    gesPts      elo

p1      2       54          1038
p2      2       54          1028
p3      0       32          956
```

what I have so far works on its own pretty good

- I count only the 1. rank for every player
- I sum up all points for every player
- and I got the elo for the last race

but I can't get it in one table result

```
SELECT T1.name,T1.rnk,T1.pts,T1.elo
FROM T1
JOIN
    (SELECT name,MAX(rce) AS lastRace
    FROM T1
    GROUP BY name) maxR

    ON (T1.rce= maxR.lastRace)

JOIN 
(SELECT name,SUM(pts) AS gesPts
    FROM T1
    GROUP BY name) gP

    ON (T1.name = gP.name)

JOIN
    (SELECT name,COUNT(rnk) as wins
    FROM T1
    WHERE rnk = 1
    GROUP BY name) Win

    ON (T1.name= Win.name)
GROUP BY name
```

I tried so many things but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using conditional aggregation. I think this might work (at least it gives the correct result given your sample data):

```
select 
    t1.name, 
    count(case when rnk = 1 then rnk end) as wins,  -- could be written as sum(rnk=1)
    sum(pts) as gespts, 
    max(case when lastrace is not null then elo end) as elo 
from t1 left join (
    select name, max(rce) as lastrace
    from t1
    group by name
) maxr on t1.rce = maxr.lastrace and t1.name = maxr.name
group by t1.name;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bfa1/2)

Comment: @Strawberry Because the elo should get the value from the last rce but the other two values should apply over the whole set. An inner join would have rendered incorrect results for the other two values. That was my thinking, I didn't spend so much time on it though - there might be better ways and my reasoning might be incorrect.